# Link Azure Devops commits to Rally user story

Tags: azure-devops, devops, rally

Our organization is transitioning from Azure Devops (VSTS) to Rally for Devops & Project management. Here are the individual responsibilities of these tools in our Product Development Lifecycle

Rally:

- Sprint Management
- User Stories/ Bugs/ Tasks/ Other Work Items
- Release Management

Azure Devops:

- GIT with Azure devops
- GIT repositories/ branches/ commit/ merge exist at azure devops
- CI/ CD pipelines

We used to bind our commits in Azure Devops to User Stories by appending '#' to work item number in each commit message.

It will take a few months for us to completely eliminate the use of Azure Devops and use a tool in conjunction with Rally (Jira or anything else). Until then I still want to be able to bind my commits at Azure Devops to the User Story in Rally.

Is that possible? Would Opshub Integration tool be of any help.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid this is currently not possible in azure devops. Linking work items to commit does not provide Rally user story for selection and there is no syntax to link Rally user story to azure devops commit.

About the Opshub Integration tool, this is described in the introduction:

> The ‘User Stories’ from Rally Software automatiscally synchronize to
>   Azure DevOps (VSTS) where they are broken down to ‘tasks’. The
>   completion of the story and the status of test results against it
>   automatically synchronizes to Rally Software.

If this tool can synchronize the `Development` field of the user story in azure devops to the Rally user story, then this goal can be achieved. Due to the additional cost, I have not actually tested this tool.

In addition, you could add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) site , which is our main forum for product suggestions.